# How do I convert column lists to web Mercator projection in python?

Tags: python, maps, bokeh, mercator

Below is converting single value columns -> to web Mercator projection:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

world_lon1, world_lat1 = transform(outProj,inProj,-180,-85)
world_lon2, world_lat2 = transform(outProj,inProj,180,85)
```

How do I convert columns with lists (like below) to -> web Mercator projection?

> **0:** [42.49273, 42.49433, 42.49562, 42.49561, 42.49472, 42.49462, 42.49481, 42.49242, 42.49489, 42.49604, 42.49624, 42.49623, 42.4969]
>
> **1:** [40.68928, 40.68985, 40.76026, 41.05548, 41.36, 41.59062, 41.89425, 41.99372, 41.99367, 41.98895, 41.99102, 41.99331, 41.99384, 41.99645, 41.99735, 41.99841, 41.99938, 41.99973, 42.00021, 42.00054, 42.00099, 42.00111]
>
> etc..

Comment: Why don't you do the same as before, but in a loop?

Comment: I don't know how to do that efficiently in Proj, but you can use the code from HoloViews (https://holoviews.org/_modules/holoviews/util/transform.html#lon_lat_to_easting_northing) or Datashader (https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/blob/25578abde75c7fa28c6633b33cb8d8a1e433da67/datashader/utils.py#L402 ) to do that. The code can be copy and pasted out if you don't want to import those libraries; it's just based on Numpy.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am not that good in python if you don't mind showing me how to that loop

Comment: Thank you @James A. Bednar